# How do I add two texts into one text area?

Tags: javascript, textarea, plaintext

I want to insert two texts into one text area using javascript.

I am getting plain text from Wikipedia but I can't seem to two or more article sections into the text area.

I use the code bellow for inserting the text for both sections into the text area.

```
pText = pText.substring(0, pText.length - 2); //Remove extra newline
pText = pText.replace(/\[\d+\]/g, ""); //Remove reference tags (e.x. [1], [4], etc)
document.getElementById('textarea').value = pText
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LUTW4/

Comment: If you want to add text at the end of the current value of the textarea, then use `.value += "new text to add"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('textarea').value += pText;
```

To add old text of the text area and new text , just concate it using `+`

This is nothing but ,

```
document.getElementById('textarea').value = document.getElementById('textarea').value + pText;
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/LUTW4/2/

Comment: Thanks that fix it! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can append more texts by

```
 document.getElementById('textarea').value = pText
 document.getElementById('textarea').value += newText
```

or even join both by

```
pText = pText+newText;
document.getElementById('textarea').value = pText
```